# How to debug ruby tests in Eclipse/Aptana Studio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, rspec, aptana

is there a way to debug all/single tests in Aptana Studio / Eclipse?

`ruby-debug19` & `ruby-debug-ide` are installed and I'm able to set breakpoints and debug my development environment, e.g. in a controller's index method. If I go to `http://localhost:3000/controler_name` eclipse opens debugging perspective and halts.

But how to do that with tests / rspec tests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to debug a ruby on rails application in eclipse, but I can't seem to make it work. ruby-debug and ruby-debug-ide are installed, but eclipse doesn't open a debugging perspective... I'm able to debug with the ruby debugger (meaning typing step for instance). How do you force eclipse to open the debugging perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a normal ruby file, right click on it and select *Debug As > Ruby application*.

If your test is a rails one that requires some setup, or you want to debug the whole suite, you'll need to generate a debug configuration manually (or edit one manually). 
*Run > Debug As > Debug configurations...* Then add an entry under *Ruby application*. Point it at your rake script path (say `/usr/local/bin/rake`) as the file to launch and then edit the arguments to pass in your app's Rakefile as the first arg and the rake task as the second arg. (i.e. `/my/path/to/project/Rakefile tests`)

Comment: Is there anything about this setup that is known not to work when using JRuby?

Comment: Is there details for the debug setup? I am setting up debug for one rspec case and not sure how to follow the instruction above.