# How do I configure Aptana 3 to run my Rails server in debug mode so it stops on breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, configuration, ruby-on-rails-5, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on Mac OS X.  I'm trying to run my server in debug mode so I can set breakpoints and step through my code.  I created the below debug configuration

[image: onfigure]

with the "server" argument ...

[image]

However, when I start my server in debug mode  (by right clicking on my project, selecting Debug As -> Debug Configurations and clicking the "Debug" button on the resulting dialog after I've selected the above configuration), the server starts up, but when I invoke code (using a curl command) to invoke the method, the curl method hangs, seemingly at the breakpoint ...

[image]

In the Aptana Studio console I see the "entered create" output, but I don't see the "done building" line.  But the Aptana IDE doesn't highlight the line where I set the breakpoint like I'd expect it to.  Below is the Aptana console.  What else do I need to do so that I can interact with the IDE properly in debug mode?

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0, debase 0.2.4.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:50900
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[79989] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[79989] * Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Love Song
[79989] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[79989] * Environment: development
[79989] * Process workers: 2
[79989] * Phased restart available
[79989] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
[79989] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[79989] - Worker 0 (pid: 80014) booted, phase: 0
[79989] - Worker 1 (pid: 80015) booted, phase: 0
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-10-13 13:44:17 -0500
  [1m[35m (5.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC[0m
Processing by UserController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"first_name"=>"Dave", "last_name"=>"Smith", "email"=>"test@example.com"}
entered create
```

Comment: The approach which you have taken is correct and as far as i know the steps to set debug configuration is also proper , but can you update the debug gems to ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25) ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12) ruby-debug19 (0.11.6) and verify once , Before that try once using rails s --debugger.

Comment: One Small question, Did you try to write a simple/normal  ruby file and then right click on it and select Debug As > Ruby application , Does the IDE opens the debug perspective ?

Answer (score 0):

The approach which you have taken is correct and as far as i know the steps to set debug configuration is also proper .

**Approach 1 to Fix :**

Use the `rails s --debugger` and check whether its working.

**Approach 2 to Fix :**

Try once by updating the to `ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25) ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12) ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)` and verify once.

**Approach 3 to Fix : Remote Debugging ::**

As the netbeans & Aptana share the same debug core , we can do a remote debugging too , the thread mentioned here can help . [Remote debugging Rails application in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760722/remote-debugging-rails-application-in-aptana-studio-3) we can follow the steps in order to ensure remote debugging works.

Basically, run the ruby app using `rdebug-ide -p 7000` (or whatever port you want), then inside the IDE, go to `Run > Debug configurations`. On the left hand side, select `"Remote Ruby Debug Session"` and then add a new configuration there (the plus icon above the list). Enter the proper host IP/name and port you entered on the command line.

**How do we debug if we have a rake file and tasks to execute ?**
If we are using a rake file and tasks to execute , you can have the reference in the thread here [How to debug ruby tests in Eclipse/Aptana Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147067/how-to-debug-ruby-tests-in-eclipse-aptana-studio/7165495)
1. Run > Debug As > Debug configurations. Then add an entry under Ruby application. Point it at your rake script path `(say /usr/local/bin/rake)` as the file to launch. 
2. The Arguements should be edited to pass in your app's Rakefile as the first arg and the rake task as the second arg. (i.e. `/my/path/to/project/Rakefile build`).

Note : 
Sometimes there might be a possibility of a specific gem causing a issue , if we remove a gem and then bundle it and try it might work out , try this if nothing works out.

Comment: Taking this step by step, I tried your approach 1.  How do I set up the Aptana debugging configuration?  I tried making my "Program Arguments "s --debugger" but when I click the "Debug" button (the button right below the "Apply" button in my first screen shot), I get the error, "cannot load such file -- rack/handler/--debugger".

Comment: The Approach 1 (rails server --debugger) which was  mentioned was to try from the console/terminal , when we just execute the command in terminal ,we can see  the below message as its starting in debugger mode => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.0 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Debugger enabled . This is to ensure that it can work from outside , when it works outside the IDE , You can just enter --debugger in arguments and try the same.

Comment: That's fair.  So running "rails s --debugger" on the command line gives the same error -- "/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/--debugger (LoadError)".

Comment: Thanks for the response dave , Do you have a environment.rb configured and if you have change the ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development" and then execute the below command "rails server -e development" is working , if it works then we will append --debugger with the command and check

Comment: we can also try with "gem install byebug" and then change the snippet to the below just to check whether the debug works through this channel , Snippet is as below . def create: print "Entered Create \n" byebug @book = buildbook(params) print "Done Building"

Comment: Hi @redhatviky, so ENV["RAILS_ENV"] was already set as development and running "rails server -e development" booted up the server normally.  Running "rails server -e development --debugger" caused the same error that I had listed in my comment above.  Are you sure "--debugger" is a valid directive with my version of RoR?  I had asked once but they seem to doubt it -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795758/getting-cannot-load-such-file-rack-handler-debugger-loaderror-when-tryi

Comment: Gotcha , I was digging deep on it and followed the link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20684 , can you try the below command :: bundle exec /Users/some/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby /Users/some/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta6/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 61019 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 61020 -- /Users/some/Repo/mrcr/timecrypt/bin/rails server Puma -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development

Comment: So I replaced "/some" with my home dir, but even still most of these paths don't exist.  For instance my ruby installation is from "/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby".  I have a "/Users/davea/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/" directory but it only has "cache" directory in it.  Is there something I need to install?